# No routes matches, empty action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I've got some rails application inherited from previous coder. 
It generates sortable tables and has helper function `sortable`

`sortable` ends like this

```
link_to title, link, {
  :class => css_class,
  :"data-direction" => direction,
  :"data-sort" => column,
  :"data-page" => params[:page].to_i.zero? ? 1 : params[:page].to_i,
  :"data-title" => params[:title],
  :"data-search-id" => params[:search_id],
  :title => "Sort `#{title}` #{direction}"}
```

`link` conatins only fields `:sort` and `:direction` 
When I try to create sortable table for my early written controller I'm getting error `(No route matches {:sort=>:company_name, :direction=>:asc, :controller=>"company"})`
I don't really understand how this code working on other controllers and where it get fields `controller` and `action`

Comment: What is the value of `link` you are passing in? Because from the error message, you specify a controller but you are not specifying an action.

Comment: Link contains only direction and sort values no controller and no action.